# How to enable all textbox controls in itemtemplate of Repeater by itemCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a repeater and I used label for display and a hidden text box which holds the same value. Now I want to enable the text box so that the user can edit inputs in the table/repeater. Can anyone help me? below is my code

```
public void FillTable()
{

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (MySqlConnection conn = Functions.GetConnection())
    {

        string sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName from tbluser LIMIT 15";



        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(table);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    asd.DataSource = table;
    asd.DataBind();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    asd.Visible = true;
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

    Literal lblname = (Literal)item.FindControl("Label2");
    TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Label3");




    if (e.CommandName == "EDIT")
    {
            lblname.Visible = false;
            txtbox.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I found a solution for this, I've used the bootstrap modal to edit a record in my table(asp.net repeater). On itemCommand event ,I get the ID and retrieve that record then bind in the modal textboxes. However , if there's an inline approach, I'd like to know it. 

Cheer(s),

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the textbox but the label twice:

```
 TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Label3");
```